# What is the best way to use try and catch in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I think the code below is the best way to use try and catch in php using PDO.

> In the catch I describe the: line number, file and errormessage

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

try{

    // code that works

}

catch(PDOException $e) 
{ 
    $errormessage = '<p> 
            Regelnummer: '.$e->getLine().'<br /> 
            Bestand: '.$e->getFile().'<br /> 
            Foutmelding: '.$e->getMessage().' 
        </p>'; 

    trigger_error($errormessage); 
}
```

If someone knows a better way to write a try and catch, please write it below.

Comment: Check the [tag:pdo]'s info page: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

Comment: The best way is [**not** to try and catch at all](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of a Class that extends PDO that might give you some ideas:

```
<?php

    //DATABASE CONNECTION CONFIGURATION:
    defined("HOST")         or define("HOST",           "localhost");
    defined("DBASE")        or define("DBASE",          "dbName");
    defined("USER")         or define("USER",           "root");
    defined("PASS")         or define("PASS",           "root");

    class DB extends PDO {

        /***
         * @var PDO
         */
        private static $dbHandle;

        public static function getInstance(){
            try {
                self::$dbHandle = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='. DBASE,USER,PASS);
                self::$dbHandle->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                return self::$dbHandle;
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        public static function getHandle(){
            if(!isset(self::$dbHandle)){
                self::$dbHandle = self::getInstance();
            }
            return self::$dbHandle;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You made it worse than without a try-catch at all

Comment: is that supposed to be a monologue or a  comment? If the latter, would you care to educate?